# flask и mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Доброго времени суток

имеется вопрос: хочу просто добавить простенький json в базу. Выдаётся ошибка, когда вызывается def get_childs_id(idd)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import flask_mongoengine
from flask_mongoengine import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {'DB': "newdb"}
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "KeepThisS3cr3t"

db = MongoEngine(app)

@app.route('/childs/<int:idd>', methods = ['GET'])
def get_childs_id(idd):
    db.insert({name : "qwerty"})
    return 'get the childs of the element ' + str(idd);

@app.route('/parents/<int:idd>', methods = ['GET'])
def get_parents_id(idd):
    return 'get the parents of the element ' + str(idd);

@app.route('/element/<int:idd>', methods = ['GET'])
def get_element(idd):
    return 'get the element ' + str(idd);

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Не увидел в вашем вопросе вопроса. Надо текст ошибки угадать?

Comment: <title>500 Internal Server Error</title> <h1> Internal Server Error </h1> <p> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to comlete ypur request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application </p>

Comment: Это тип ошибки http-ошибки, обозначающий, что произошла какая-то ошибка в коде сервера. Определить что конкретно произошло можно только по полному тексту конкретной ошибки. Искать его надо или в консоли при запуске сервера в отладочном режиме или в логах.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки

Comment: ошибка в коде. Неверно генерирую запрос на добавление документа. Как быть - вообще без понятия. Многие работают с pymongo, но мне нужен именно mongoengine

Comment: Без полного текста ошибки шанс получить помощь у вас мизерный.

Comment: вот полный текст ошибки 
 
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title> <h1> Internal Server Error </h1> <p> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to comlete ypur request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application </p>

Comment: установите `FLASK_DEBUG=1` переменную окружения или `app.run(debug=True)`. Полученный traceback прямо в вопрос добавьте. Нажмите [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй заменить строку:

```
db.insert({name: "qwerty"})
```

на

```
db.insert({"name": "qwerty"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Как уже написали выше, у вас ключ словаря не определен. Нужно либо определить переменную `name`, либо сделать ключ строкой. Но это не поможет, так как для работы с `mongoengine` необходимо описать модели.

Изучите сначала `mongoengine` безотносительно `flask`, поймите как работает этот ORM. У него есть достаточно хорошая [документация](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html). Вам нужно описать модели ORM, и с ними уже работать - вставлять, читать, изменять. При этом вам не нужно запускать веб-сервер, делать какие то запросы.

После этого можете интегрировать `mongoengine` и `flask`, например через расширение `flask-mongoengine`. Там кстати есть [примеры приложений](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/tree/master/examples)